# Add field Netsuite amortization schedule

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I would like to add a few fields to the amortization schedule record in Netsuite.  However my user event script does not run.  I used netsuite's debugger and when I view the record it doesn't even seem to recognize that there is a user event script. The script below works perfectly on other record types like a customer record but I can not get it to work on the amortization schedule record.

```js
function addFieldsBeforeLoad(type, form, request){
 form.addField('custpage_test', 'text', 'test');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly mentioned in NetSuite help that -

This record is scriptable in server SuiteScript only.

**The user events are not supported.**

Hope this will help.